# How can I change feign client Logger.Level level dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm writing a spring boot app and use spring-cloud-starter-openfeign. It will be rather convenient to change logger level dynamically (through API call, for example) but I can't find the way to do it without creating a new feign client manually. It seems I need to get access to feign client implementation and to get its properties. There I probably can set a new Logger level but haven't managed to find the way ho to do this. Does anyone have ideas on how to do it, or someone might face similar issues?